# Close modal by sending the esc key in the browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, dialog, modal-dialog

all modals can close using press esc key by human.
I want to do this through javascript code without actual human intervention
I run the following code through the browser console, but it does not work at all
Can anyone solve my problem?

```
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'Escape'}));
```

To test, you can go to [the link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) and test

Comment: @Yogi i dont use any method like css \ click  to close modal

Comment: Then you likely could change this, this is how it's normally done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```js
document.getElementById('myModal').dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown",{
        keyCode: 27,
        which: 27,
        key: 'Escape',
        code: 'Escape'
     }));
```

Comment: While this may cause the modal to close, it is not the recommended way to close a Bootstrap modal. Instead, it is better to use the built-in hide() method provided by Bootstrap, as it handles the closing animation and other related tasks.

Comment: Yes, I forgot one big thing
A thing called focus
Thankful

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work.

```
<!-- HTML code for the Bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal header, body, and footer content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript code to listen for the escape key press -->
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Escape") {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    if ($(modal).data('bs.modal')._isShown) {
      $(modal).modal('hide');
    }
  }
});
</script>
```